# Same raytracer code returns different results (cmake)

Tags: c++, ubuntu, cmake

For our final assignment, a friend and I are creating a Raytracer in c++. We're working with Github and cmake. Everything was working fine, until we implemented shadows and refractions. These work fine on my friends computer, but not on mine. The shadows don't work at all and the refraction has got a lot of black dots on it. Another weird thing is, that std::couts from the main file don't get displayed in the terminal after executing, but I'm definitely working on the correct file (I still get errors when writing random stuff in it).

Tried pretty much everything from cloning again, copying the files over usb and updating the compiler.

Since we're working with floats I thought it could be a result of floating point inaccuracy, but i guess that wouldn't explain the missing prints...
Don't really know, which part of the code would be helpful, but i can post any. He's using Ubuntu 15.04 on 64bit and I'm using 14.04 on the same machine.

I hope, somebody can help me here!

Edit: Okay, just tried to print something from an included file, works just fine. But still no print from the main file..

Comment: If you don't know which part of code to post, then you don't know where the error is. Which means you must pinpoint it. Start removing blocks (`#if 0`, comment out, that sort of thing), testing after each removal, until the problem disappears. Then you'll be much closer to finding the error.

Comment: Well, seems like you've got undefined behaviour. Try looking for uninitialized values, unsafe pointers or some bad cast. Try enabling warnings, it should help you.

Comment: instead of 
`cout << "output\n";`
Try
`cout << "ouput" << endl;`
The endl will fush the buffer, forcing the application to print

Comment: Try to compile with all optimizations disabled on both computers, so in debug mode ... Some aggressive optimizations sometimes can cause such issues. Also do you use random number generators in the raytracing code with a harcoded seed ? Maybe the different behavior (excluding cout) would come from the random number sequence being different on the computers...

Comment: Add logging for EVERYTHING, and look for the first place where it diverges. Trace back and see why it differs. Could be different compiler versions (quite likely) or just "undefined behaviour" and subtle differences such as the location one machine loads the data/code with address space randomisation.

Answer (score 1):

The reasons for this difference of the behaviour can be:

1. Try to identify a place in the program where the difference occurs the first time. For that you can try to log some events, like entering and leaving functions, values of `if` statement predicates where you make some decisions, etc. You can also add checks of invariants (using `assert` statements or similar).
2. Undefined behaviour is a most likely cause of such problems. It can be uninitialized variables, out of bounds memory access, etc. To check that, compile with `-Wall -Wextra` (or even `-Weverything` in Clang), use [sanitizers](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html), for example `-fsanitize=address,undefined` (available in GCC and Clang). You can also use Valgrind to catch such errors, or some static analysis tools.
3. Difference in versions of some libraries. Log the return values of the library calls to make sure the behaviour of the third-party libraries is the same.
4. If the program is multi-threaded, and there is a race condition, the program can exhibit the behaviours you describe. So, pay attention to thread-correctness. You can use thread sanitizer to catch that.
5. (Unlikely, as you already concluded youself) Difference in compiler versions and optimizations. Depending on optimizations applied, floating point operations can give slightly different results. Try different optimization levels to see if the problem depends on that.